# How to open multiple modal in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I use `mat-dialog` in a a project and there is a form field (dropdown) called course in this dialog. I want to open another dialog in order to add a course record that is not available in the course list dropdown. At this step, I am wondering what is a proper way for this scenario.

Should I open the second dialog inside the first dialog by setting the form fields of the second one?

Or is it better just hiding first dialog and showing second and then after completing the operation on the second, close second ad show first one?

If there is a demo of a proper approach for opening dialog on another I would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your preference, requirement and the library you have chosen. Since you have already mentioned that you are using material dialog, it works fine with nested unlike bootstrap-modal. So, If I were you, I  would go with nested modal by properly configuring `z index` and `backdrop`.

You can check [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/multiple-dialogs-so?file=app%2Fdialog2.component.ts) demo just to get idea,

Comment: Seems to be good, but what about hiding the first dialog while keeping its data after opening second dialog? Could you pls update your answer for this scenario?